# Is there a way to detect SVG support?

Tags: office-js

It looks like some versions of Office support SVG files now, and I've confirmed that I can add them via `setSelectedDataAsync`. Is there a way to detect whether the app my add-in is running in supports SVG? I'd like to add SVG when possible and fall back to PNG when necessary.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-SVG-images-in-Microsoft-Office-2016-69F29D39-194A-4072-8C35-DBE5E7EA528C?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US